# Can I use: "TextEntered.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("a")" to count chars in a string?

Tags: c#, foreach, count, chars

I'm trying to count vowels in a certain string inputted by a user. So if there are 6 A's in a sentence that the user inputs via a `console.Readline();` the console should return `A=6`. The final output is supposed to look a bit like:

```
A =?  
I =?  
E =?  
O =?  
U =?
```

Note the ?'s are representative of the number of vowels detected in the string.

I have a few ideas and a step by step, for example "`textEntered.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("a")`" as mentioned in the title. Would this work? I've been told this may just return true every time that a vowel is detected. If so, could I set true in such a way that it increments the count?

I have also tried to find a solution on https://www.dotnetperls.com/count-characters but this doesn't seem to have the desired output.

I think the best way would be to use a `foreach` loop in some way to loop the character search!

If not, what is the most efficient way to code this? Thanks! (please bare in mind that I'm a student still getting to grips with the language, please be kind!)

Comment: Why don't you test that yourself?

Comment: Haha, good question. I have been trying other methods and just wanted to know if this was possible as I wouldn't know the code I'd need to form an output doing it this way

Comment: It's possible with a for loop... go write it, if you get stuck come back with examples. Don't focus on the most efficient way to do 'x'. Learn the basics of flow control you will be much better off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Count:

```
int countOfA = textEntered.Count(x => x == 'a');
```

EDIT:

```
int countOfA = textEntered.ToUpper().Count(x => x == 'A');
```

Comment: What about `'A'`

Comment: @stuartd OK so OP could use ToUpper() method as he had mentioned.

Comment: Oh wow, I tried count but it wouldn't work. Turns out I was missing using System.Linq; ... rookie error